# Autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have an issue with the auto complete in js. Here the following code works well for me:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#txtAuto" ).autocomplete({
        source: ["Choice1","Choice2"],
        minLength:2     
    });
});
```

But when I change this to the code below for testing it doesn't gives me choices:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#txtAuto" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ){
            $.ajax({
                url: "test.ewd",
                success: function(data){
                    var res=data.match('\\[[^\\]]*]');
                    return ["Choice1", "Choice2"];                       
                }
            });
        },
        minLength:2     
    });
});
```

Any one tell me where I did mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The core of the problem is that the ajax-function is asynchronous. It is not executed at the same time as the rest of your code, but rather when the response for your ajax-request (which probably takes 10-100 ms to complete) is available.

So, you can't `return` the values from the `success`-function. Instead, you must pass them in to the `response` function. like this:

```
success: function(data) {
  var res=data.match('\\[[^\\]]*]');
  response(["Choice1", "Choice2"]);
}
```

Comment: No problem. There's a button next to my answer that you can use to "accept" the answer. It will show others that this was the working solution.